# What does `-f` flag mean when used in a shebang: `#!/bin/bash -f`?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

what does shebang -f flag means? Specifically it is used in bash cript file,

```sh
#!/bin/bash -f
echo hello
# blabla
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It passes the `-f` flag to the `bash` instance which runs the script:

From `$ bash -c "help set"`:

```
 -f  Disable file name generation (globbing).
```

From https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/options.html:

```
Abbreviation    Name    Effect

-f              noglob  Filename expansion (globbing) disabled
```

Comment: A fine answer, but perhaps also point out that this depends on which interpreter is being specified. For example, `#!/usr/bin/sed -f` is quite common, and means something entirely different. In fact, for `csh` and `sed` and `awk` and a number of other tools, the `-f` option is mandatory when you put them in the shebang, and says to read commands from this file.